# Multiple component instances overrides callback for custom binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Supporting fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lezhnev_dmitriy/5Lvq1nra/

```js
$(function(){

// when DOM ready

ko.bindingHandlers.button = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
                    this.onClick = valueAccessor();
                    $(element).html('<button data-bind="click: onClick">Click</button>');
                },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
                },
};

ko.components.register('comp1', {
 template: '<div>component instance <span data-bind="text: instance_id"></span> <span data-bind="button: handleClick"></span></div>',
  viewModel: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.instance_id = ko.observable(Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)); // debug purpose

    self.handleClick = function () {
      alert('clicked at ' + self.instance_id());
    }.bind(this); // very interesting hint!
  }
});

ko.applyBindings();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<comp1></comp1>
<comp1></comp1>
```

I have two components and each injects custom binding (`button`) in its template. Then it attaches a callback to that binding. 
But only last binding works (both buttons now handled via the last component instance).

Am I missing something?

UPDATE:
I found out that this code actually will work

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.button = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
                    var self = this;
                    self.onClick = valueAccessor();
                    $(element).html('<button>Click</button>');
                    $('button', element).click(self.onClick);
                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel_deprecated, bindingContext) {
                    var self = this;

                },
            };

            ko.components.register('comp1', {
                template: '<div>component instance <span data-bind="text: instance_id"></span> <span data-bind="button: handleClick"></span></div>',
                viewModel: function () {
                    var self = this;
                    self.instance_id = ko.observable(Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)); // debug purpose

                    self.handleClick = function () {
                        console.log('clicked at ' + self.instance_id());
                    }.bind(this); // very interesting hint!
                }
            });
            
ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<comp1></comp1>
<comp1></comp1>
```

Comment: I found out this workaround: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2263

Comment: try using the createViewModel function, I've had 0 problems using that.

Comment: Tried it myself, same problem. I think the problem comes from adding DOM elements by code in the bindingHandler. You're supposed to use templates for that I guess. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lvq1nra/2/

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you're not supposed to be changing DOM nodes within code of a bindingHandler.
We have templates for that reason.

```
<script id="buttonTemplate" type="text/html">
    <button data-bind="click: handleClick">Click</button>
</script>    

template: '<div>component instance <span data-bind="text: instance_id"></span> <span data-bind="template: {name: \'buttonTemplate\', data: $data }"></span></div>',
```

I've updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lvq1nra/2/

Edit: Passing the $data into the data property of a template is not really needed (default), just to show you can pass an object as a model.

Comment: I feel that template may not fit my case. Anyway, let me tell you what I have and maybe you can advice me a better way?

I have an SPA which can have multiple pages. Each page is a powered by a knockout component (searching filter at the top and results at the bottom). 

Searching filter powered by the custom binding. 

So component injects the searching widget in its template and passes callback to get notified when search initiated.

The widget itself is complex enough to be a good candidate for a custom binding with custom html and DOM events.

Does it make sense to you?